# What happens to a photon sent to an atom has no electrons?

Tags: photons, electrons

Suppose that there is an atom has no electrons.
If we sent a photon to this atom, what would happen? Reflected or absorbed?

Comment: An atom, by definition, has at least one electron. Can photons interact with naked nuclei? Absolutely. They can be scattered and at higher energies they can cause nuclear reactions.

Comment: Will naked nuclei by your term be visible or not?

Comment: Of course they are visible. Why should they be invisible? The electric field of a naked nucleus is enormously strong and it interacts very strongly with an electromagnetic field.

Comment: I meant to say that if we sent a light to it, would it reflect back?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by scattering. That's what they do in accelerator experiments like LHC. The scattering of low energy photons is not very interesting, though, we understand it very well. Today we are studying the scattering of very energetic particles on other particles.

Comment: That is new for me. Do they have any colors?

Comment: Yes, nuclei have "colors", they are just not visible but in the gamma ray wavelength range. Here is an energy level diagram for 12C, the most common carbon nucleus: http://www2.lbl.gov/abc/wallchart/chapters/06/0.html

Comment: What is the change on the nuclei when it absorbs a light in the visible spectrum?

Comment: It probably won't absorb in the visible spectrum but it will scatter light. As you can see from the transparency of solids and liquids (the scattering length can be hundreds of meters in clear water or ice and that's still caused by impurities and electronic excitations) that scattering of nuclei would be very faint.